# .Jar não executa

Tags: java, jar

Estou com um problema na hora de executar um *arquivo.jar* que eu fiz.

Quando clico em executar não acontece simplesmente nada, nenhuma janela abre, nenhuma mensagem de erro nem nada.

Na pasta do *Meta-INF* possui o arquivo *MANIFEST.MF* contendo apenas `Manifest-Version: 1.0`.

O nome do `PACK` é `REDE` e a classe que possui o `main` que estou querendo executar eé `chatserver`.

O que eu devo fazer para que seja executado?

Comment: Como vc gerou esse jar? Foi a através de linha de comando?

Comment: Reinstala o java, e tenta de novo.

Comment: Como assim "reinstala o Java"? @cypherpotato

Comment: .jar é um executável do Java, as vezes o erro pode estar no seu Java...

Comment: Só para saber, já tentou rodar por linha de comando `java -jar arquivo.jar`? Se sim, o que ele mostra no console e o que acontece depois de você fazer isso? Se você executar `java -version`, o que é mostrado? Com qual compilador o JAR foi gerado?

Comment: Alguma exceção pode estar ocorrendo. Tente fazer o que o @VictorStafusa disse: execute por linha de comando e veja o que mostra no console.

Answer (score 1):

Como você diz já ter o arquivo MANIFEST.MF dentro da pasta META-INF, o que lhe falta agora é indicar nesse arquivo o endereço completo da sua classe principal, assim:

> Main-Class: com.pacote.Classe

Para seu caso ficaria:

> Main-Class: REDE.chatserver

Entretanto, observe que tanto o nome do seu pacote como o nome da sua classe fogem da convenção de nomenclaturas definido pelo JavaBeans Standard, que diz que pacotes devem ser escritos em minúsculo, enquanto classes devem seguir o padrão `PascalCase`, logo, o mais apropriado seria que o endereço completo da sua classe fosse: `rede.ChatServer`